# Will a readonly property with a custom getter have an instance variable synthesized?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a situation where I don't want instance variables synthesized for a set of properties (I'm managing them via User Defaults and Keychain).

If I have the following, `_loginUsername` will for sure be synthesized:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *loginUsername;
```

And I know if I had the following, an instance variable would not be synthesized, because the declaration is saying "I'm going to take care of it myself":

```
@property (nonatomic, getter = loginUsername, setter = setLoginUsername) NSString *loginUsername;
```

Is the behavior the same for a readonly property with a custom getter?:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = loginUsername) NSString *loginUsername;
```

Will there be a `_loginUsername` synthesized for the final property declaration? I'm fairly sure that there won't, but I'm trying to get a better grasp of property attributes so want to make sure I'm not way off.

Bonus points for explaining whether this is known at compile time (no cheating and checking in Xcode!).

I don't have any `@synthesize` statements in my implementation file.

Comment: "no cheating and checking in Xcode!" wait, what?

Comment: @ChrisWagner - ok ok, you can check Xcode :) but I'd like to know how it knows pre runtime. I guess just simple static analysis - I can't think of a more complex scenario which would result in uncertainty at compile time

Comment: I don't know the specifics well enough to answer this, but I will add that with `@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = loginUsername) NSString *loginUsername;` I can still compile code that has `_loginUsername = nil;` in my implementation. Furthermore, I can still do that when I have `@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = loginUsername, setter = setLoginUsername:) NSString *loginUsername;` It seems like the docs are lying!

Comment: Xcode IntelliSense should tell if its available, just type `_loginUsername' after you have custom getter and setters defined. I bet it will complain!

Comment: @ChrisWagner - I just tried and its a compile time error if you have getting or settings defined in your implementation file and still try to use `_loginUsername`. Just setting them on `@property` declaration does not do anything!

Comment: Hmm, that's strange because I get a compile error immediately when referencing _loginUsername. Same error regardless of whether it's a class property or class extension.

Comment: Yep, same for me @YasKuraishi, http://i.imgur.com/KcmNcrh.png

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Note: The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable
>   in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor
>   method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite
>   property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will
>   assume that you are taking control over the property implementation
>   and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically. If you still
>   need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be
>   synthesized

[Programming with Objective-c - Encapsulating data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) - under **You Can Implement Custom Accessor Methods**

Comment: Bingo! That was my hunch. Thanks for clearing that up @m-porooshani

Comment: @bdalziel I have been an apple developer for quite some time now, but I always enjoy reading Apple's programming guides, they are simply awesome and they shed light on subjects that are both mundane and important and most likely invisible in our daily jobs. give them a try. I answered your question because I remembered I've had read about it a few weeks ago in the guide I've mentioned in my answer. Good like my friend.